# Magento Checkout Process

Tags: magento

I have added a custom module to remove the login step from my store checkout process making the billing details the first step. I want to show the billing details form even if the customer is logged out. I am not sure how to change this below code to achieve what I want.

```
<?php
class Step_Removal_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage
{
    public function getSteps()
    {
        $steps = array();

        if (!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
            //$steps['login'] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData('login');
        }

        $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');

        foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
            $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
        }
        return $steps;
    }

    public function getActiveStep()
    {
        //return $this->isCustomerLoggedIn() ? 'billing' : 'login';
        return $this->isCustomerLoggedIn() ? 'billing' : 'billing';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct - what is it returning?

Comment: its returning the checkout page without the login form BUT the Billing form isn't active. Trying to make the Billing Information form active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code

```
foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
    $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
}
return $steps;
```

with

```
foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
    $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
}
$steps['billing']['allow']=1;
return $steps;
```